# Eclipse debugging automatically skip "source not found"

Tags: eclipse, debugging

while debugging i have some jar files without the source.
If I debug via "step in" (F5) I get a error "source not found".

I know the cause of this "error", but I want to automatically skip this error while debugging.

Is this possible?